# Mix compiliation fails when compiling Ecto

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, ecto

In Elixir:
When trying to compile the dependencies for Ecto, I run into the following error with Mix and poolboy:

```
>mix compile
```

> ** (Mix) The application poolboy specified a non Semantic Version `cat VERSION`. Mix can only match the requirement ~> 1.2.1 against Semantic Versions, to match against any version, please use a regex as requirement

I'm on Windows 8.1

Here are my mix deps:
Note: I have to use "~> 0.6.0" for postgrex or else it complain of dependency resolution.  (In Ecto docs, it just says to use ">= 0.0.0")

```
defp deps do
[
  {:postgrex, "~> 0.6.0"},
  {:ecto, "~> 0.2.5"}
]
end
```

From the compile error message, it seems that either mix is not handling something properly or poolboy isn't and may not be on the Ecto side?

Anyways, anyone know how to fix this or have a workaround?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding Poolboy as a dependency directly?  I mean like defp deps do [{postgrex, "~> 0.6.0"}, {:ecto, "~> 0.2.5"},{:poolboy, "~> 1.2.1"}] end

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci - Just tried it, didn't work, same result.

Comment: It seems that poolboy is trying to set the version via cat (https://github.com/devinus/poolboy/blob/master/src/poolboy.app.src#L3). I'd say this is definitely a poolboy problem, so you may want to open up an issue on the poolboy repo.

Comment: You may be able to build things if you use Cygwin or MinGW on Windows.  You could also grab the cat command for Windows from here: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ or here: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poolboy bug. Rebar (Erlang build tool) allows users to inject custom code in their application files and poolboy is using this feature to read the VERSION from the filesystem using specific OS commands. It works on Linux but it is going to fail on Windows. I have opened an issue on Poolboy issues tracker.

Comment: So, devinus has coded in hardcoded fix for now.  Which is to use the hardcoded version instead of using the 'cat' command, since Windows doesn't have it.  It may not be the best solution for the future though, but it works now.